# Get Three legged token with Node js Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Is there a simpler way to generate a three legged token only using Node js.
I have used the method in the [1]: https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/oauth/3legged/nodejs, but I am looking for a  simpler method, that just gives me the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard workflow for a 3-legged OAuth token (not just for Forge but for any [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2) provider) is typically:

1. You redirect the user to Autodesk login form
2. You wait for a callback from the Autodesk login form (assuming the user logged in successfully), and retrieve a temporary code
3. You exchange the temporary code for an actual access token (and a *refresh* token)

This process is explained in the [docs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/) as well.

Another option that is perhaps a bit simpler is using the ["implicit grant"](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token-implicit) where the step 3 is basically skipped, and the access token is included directly in the callback. The downside of this approach is that you do not receive the *refresh* token.